# python converting a list of strings into variable names

Tags: python

Ok so Basically I have this list.
pets = ["mypets","herpets","hispets"]

and as this list was generated from reading the lines of a text file

```
textfile = open("pets", 'r')
lines = textfile.read()
words = lines.splitlines()
print(words)
```

I am now trying to find a way to convert this list from a list of strings
into a list of variable names

```
pets = [mypets,herpets,hispets]
```

I would also like to point out that my issue is not in how to construct a list of variables as there may of been a missunderstanding.

Comment: Why don't you save those `mypets` lists as dictionary?

Comment: the 3 pets,  mypets, herpets and hispets are imported from an external text file

Comment: I answered you. If it is suitable to save arrays with the animals themselves in the 'pets' list. Or do I need to have strings in 'pets'?

Comment: Is the idea of accessing variables from their names in `["mypets","herpets","hispets"]` your own, or a requirement for some school assignment? In practice this is considered a _bad idea™_ , so if this is within your control, you'd be best to avoid it. See [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1373164/11082165) for more on why

Comment: @Brian its kind of out of my control, as the variable names for the list pets, is imported from a text file

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1373164/11082165). You don't need to create a list of variable names. What you do need is to associate some strings (mypets, herpets, hispets) with some lists of strings that you read from text files. That kind of associated mapping is exactly what dictionaries are for.

Answer (score 1):

Much better to use a dictionary as @Ynjxsjmh suggested:

```
all_pets = {
    'mypets': ['cat','dog','snake'],
    'herpets': ['bird','hamster','rabbit'],
    'hispets': ['fox','bees','worms'],
}
owners = ["mypets","herpets","hispets"]

for owner in owners:
    print(all_pets[owner])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pets = [mypets, herpets, hispets]
print(pets[0][0])
```

Output

```
cat
```

Comment: i'm looking to convert pets=["mypets","herpets","hispets"] into pets=[mypets,herpets,hispets] as I am first stuck with strings